# Push multiple objects into single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am looking at pushing multiple Json objects into 1 single object.

Currently I am parsing an array from AJAX and it console logs like this

```
0:{id: "24", user: "Joe", pass: "pass", name: "Joe Bloggs", role: "Technical Support", …}
1:{id: "25", user: "Jim", pass: "pass", name: "Jim Bloggs", role: "Technical Support", …}
2:{id: "26", user: "John", pass: "pass", name: "John Bloggs", role: "Technical Support", …}
```

I need to run a loop and push all of the id's and user's into a single line, in this exact format

```
0: {Joe : 24, Jim : 25, John : 26}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the data to a new object:

```js
let a = [{id: "24", user: "Joe", pass: "pass", name: "Joe Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"},
{id: "25", user: "Jim", pass: "pass", name: "Jim Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"},
{id: "26", user: "John", pass: "pass", name: "John Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"}]

let res = a.reduce((a,b) => {
    a[b.user] = b.id;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Or if you prefer destructuring

```js
let a = [{id: "24", user: "Joe", pass: "pass", name: "Joe Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"},
{id: "25", user: "Jim", pass: "pass", name: "Jim Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"},
{id: "26", user: "John", pass: "pass", name: "John Bloggs", role: "Technical Support"}]

let res = {};
for (let {id, user} of a) {
    res[user] = id;
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How do I do this, but pass in a parseJSON result from an AJAX request?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just replace `a.reduce` with `<yourArrayVariable>.reduce` @Sam

Comment: Sorry, using the destructing method I want to pass in an object I have fetched from an AJAX call. `success: function(results) {var result = .parseJSON(results);`

Comment: Then replace `let {id, user} of a` with `let {id, user} of result`... @Sam

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns _resu;t[symbol.iterator] is not a function_

Comment: Then your data is different from what you’ve posted. @Sam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153148/discussion-between-sam-and-baao).